# How to draw a dotted line between two nodes in latex

Tags: tikz-pgf

How to draw a dotted line between two nodes in latex. I used the below command but I am not able to connect the two nodes 3 and 4 by a dotted line.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=3cm,
        thick,main node/.style={circle,draw,font=\sffamily\Large\bfseries}]

    \node[main node] (1) {$1$};
    \node[main node] (2) [above of=1] {$2$};
    \node[main node] (3) [above of=2] {$3$};
    \node[main node] (4) [above of=3] {$4$};
    \path[every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}]
    (1)  edge node [above] {} (2)
    edge [loop left] node {} (1) (1)
    (2)  edge node [above] {} (3)
    edge [loop left] node {} (2) (2)
    (3) edge node [above] {} (4)
    edge [loop left] node {} (3) (3);

    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Try this: `edge[dotted]`

Answer (score 1):

As @C.F.G mentioned in his comment, add option `\dotted` to the edge, which should be dotted. I also employ library `positioning` and slightly rearrange your code:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,
                positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto,
    node distance = 12mm,
every edge/.style = {draw, -stealth', shorten >=1pt, thick},
 main node/.style = {circle,draw,font=\Large\sffamily\bfseries}
                        ]
\node[main node] (1)                {$1$};
\node[main node] (2) [above=of 1]   {$2$};
\node[main node] (3) [above=of 2]   {$3$};
\node[main node] (4) [above=of 3]   {$4$};
%
\path[every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}]
    (1) edge                node [right] {} (2)
        edge [loop left]    node {} () 
    (2) edge                node [right] {} (3)
        edge [loop left]    node {} ()
    (3) edge [dotted]       node [right] {} (4) % <---
        edge [loop left]    node {} ();
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Do you will label edges? So far nodes are empty. If you will not, than delete them.

[image]